# I want to display some data in the popup (popup should not be the ajax control). I was trying to do it by placing a grid within grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a gridview and I want to display some data in the popup (popup should not be the ajax control).I was trying to do it by placing a gridview within gridview like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdInspectionApprovel" runat="server" Width="99%" EmptyDataText="<%$ Resources:Captions,grdEmptyPeriods%>"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" Style="margin-bottom: 1px" CssClass="grdviewbrd"
    OnRowDataBound="grdInspectionApprovel_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="grdInspectionApprovel_RowCommand"
    OnRowCreated="grdInspectionApprovel_RowCreated" OnRowEditing="grdInspectionApprovel_RowEditing">
    <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="emptyRow1" />
    <PagerSettings Visible="false" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AtlernatingRowStyle" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="POPUP" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="simplediv" style="background-color: White; border: 1px solid black; display: none;
                    width: 70%; height: 200px;">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <input type="image" src="~/App_Themes/MyWebTheme/images/imgError.gif" id="imageButton"
                                    onclick="Popup.hide('simplediv');return false;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:GridView ID="grdInspectionApprovelPOPUP" runat="server" Width="98%" EmptyDataText="<%$ Resources:Captions,grdEmptyPeriods%>"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" Style="margin-bottom: 1px" CssClass="grdviewbrd">
                                    <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
                                    <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="emptyRow1" />
                                    <PagerSettings Visible="false" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AtlernatingRowStyle" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Captions,lblSupplierSINo%>" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSupplierSINo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SupplierSerialNo") %>'
                                                    Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <headerstyle cssclass="gridtophead" />
                                                <itemstyle horizontalalign="Center"></itemstyle>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid_title" />
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="deletebtn1" CommandName="btnSave" ImageUrl="<%$ Resources:Paths,imgBtnSave%>" />
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="deletebtn" CommandName="btnSave" Text="Save"></asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Captions,btnReset%>"
                                    CssClass="btnStyle" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <a href="#" onclick="Popup.show('simplediv');return false;">+</a>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkbtnPopup" CommandName="callPopup" Text="++"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("WOID")  %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></FooterStyle>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridtophead" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="2%"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Captions,lblSrNo%>" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblWO" Text='<%# Eval("WOID") %>' runat="server" Style="display: none;"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAssetID" Text='<%# Eval("AssetID") %>' runat="server" Style="display: none;"></asp:Label>
                <%#(Convert.ToInt32(hfPageIndex.Value) * grdInspectionApprovel.PageSize) + Container.DataItemIndex + 1%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></FooterStyle>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridtophead" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="2%"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid_title" />
</asp:GridView>
```

and `Popup.show('simplediv')` this function is from javascript file. I want to bind the chield gridview on each rowCommand of parent gridview and want to display this gridview on popup div.

Comment: Outside ASP, the term "grid" is seldom used. Try tagging question with [asp.net] to attract the right experts.

Comment: my problem gets solved... thank you